# Libgdx couldn't load animation was baked from physics

Tags: android, libgdx, blender

I designed a model in Blender3d. It had an animation which was baked from physics, named "flag". After that, I imported it to my game but I can't see my animation. I used add-in Libgdx exporter for Blender.
Here is my code:

```
    ...public void create () {
    environment=new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f));
    batch=new ModelBatch();

    assetManager=new AssetManager();
    assetManager.load(NAME,Model.class);
    loading=true;
}
private void doneLoading(){
    instance=new ModelInstance(assetManager.get(NAME,Model.class));
    if(useAnimation){
    animationController=new AnimationController(instance); //Can't find my animation name
    animationController.setAnimation(ANI,-1);}
    loading=false;
}...
```

[Screenshot blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JAWD.png)

[Screenshot debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvAPv.png)

Please help me. Thank you very much.